# Vim & GAE - Is there anyway to debug python gae applications using vim?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, vim

I know that there are plugins to debugging python in vim like this one:https://github.com/joonty/vdebug

What I'm struggling is to find a way to debug GAE apps, is that even possible? If so what steps should I take to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running the GAE app locally with the development server, you should be able to debug the python runtime the same way that you'd debug other local processes.

You can't use vim to debug processes running on the Google runtimes in Google's datacenters. You might be able to use the [Stackdriver Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/) to get stack traces; according to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setting-up-python-on-app-engine), the debugger is supported with Python on both the standard and the python-compat flex runtimes.

Comment: And here are the instructions for [using pdb on the local development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server#Python_Debugging_with_PDB)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want (debug python locally) :)